# how to change a class's class attributes' default value

Tags: python, class

i have a class test with a class attribute strategy, which has two int attributes short_window=10, long_window=40.

```
class test(object):

    def __init__(self, symbol,strategy ):
       """  
       Parameters:
       symbol - The list strings.
       strategy - (Class).
       """
       self.symbol = symbol
       self.strategy_cls = strategy
   
       self._generate_instances()

   def _generate_instances(self):

       self.strategy = self.strategy_cls(self.data)   

class Strategy(Object):

    def __init__(self, data，short_window=100, long_window=400):
       """
       Initialises the Moving Average Cross Strategy.

       Parameters:
       short_window - The short moving average lookback.
       long_window - The long moving average lookback.
       """
       self.data = data
       self.short_window = short_window
       self.long_window = long_window
```

i would like to give new values to two attributes values in loops, but i don't know how to change those values. it seems the codes below does't work. pls, help me!

```
a_test = test(symbol,strategy(data, 2,3 ))
```

Comment: `strategy` should be `Strategy`.

Comment: Why does `test` take a class instead of an instance of that class?

Comment: yes, strategy should be Strategyl. my bad

Comment: @ user2357112 supports Monica, good question,acturally because data is another classs, i think class gives more flexibility

Answer (score 0):

Since a class is used as a function to create instances, you can use a lambda.

```
a_test = test(symbol, lambda data: Strategy(data, 2, 3))
```